# How to get the first 2 records from Access's Table and Add them to Jtable (Data filter)

Tags: java, arrays, ms-access

> String[] Titulo = {
>        "ID",
>       "CDEP",
>       "NOMDEP",
>        "POB"
>       }; //This is the head of the Jtable

```
Mnc2 = new DefaultTableModel(null, Titulo);
String[] Filas = new String[4];

try { //HERE IS THE CONECTION TO THE BDD(ACCESS)
Conexion_DDB Conn = new Conexion_DDB();

//Prepared Query
PreparedStatement Consulta = Conn.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM [DEPARTAMENTOS]");
 ResultSet Resultadobm = Consulta.executeQuery();

while (Resultadobm.next()) { 
 //This is the part thath I don't know how to get the Strings or values for each row 
 Filas[0] = Resultadobm.getString("CDEPID"); 
 Filas[1] = Resultadobm.getString("CDEP");
 Filas[2] = Resultadobm.getString("POBDEP");
 Filas[3] = Resultadobm.getString("NOMDEP");

//There are more records but just for example
```

> while (Resultadobm.next()) { 
>        //This is the part thath I don't know how to get the Strings or values for the first two rows

```
Mnc2.addColumn(Filas);//Add the columns
}
/*At this part, I'm trying to get the values equals or higher than 50,000 to show then in the same table at the same time with the two first records found*/

//If you can help me here too I would appreciate it a lot

int Menora = 50000;
if (Mnc2.getValueAt(1, 1).equals(Menora)) {
Tabla_Busquedas.setValueAt(Mnc2, 1, 1);
}

Conn.Desconexion(); //Close the connection
} catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Form_Tabla.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while (Resultadobm.next()) { //This is the part thath I don't know how
>   to get the Strings or values for the first two rows

I am not sure I understand right.I think you can terminate the loop after you fetched first two rows:

```
while (Resultadobm.next() && Resultadobm.getRow() <= 2) { 
  // ...your code
}
```

Comment: Tanks "fanshaoer", you got me the idea... This is the correct way to show all the records from 2 rows: while (Resultadobm.next()&&Resultadobm.getRow()<=2) {

Comment: @MasterBitco05 yes,you are right than me.Resultadobm.next() should be right.I will modify it,thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the source:

```
"SELECT TOP 2 * FROM [DEPARTAMENTOS] ORDER BY [SomeUniqueField]");
```

Comment: I tried in this way but it doesn't work. Thank you anyway Gustav.